# A reputation change isn't being displayed on my profile

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

Yesterday I had 3,606 reputation but today I have 3,592.

My profile shows that I lost 6 reputation when a user was removed, but that would put me on 3,600 - 8 reputation has magically disappeared.

Adding up all of my reputation does work out at 3,591 (I'm assuming by default new users have 1 rep, so that would make sense).

Somewhere a reputation change since yesterday isn't being displayed. I don't know what this would be for, but -8 would lead me to believe that someone removed their up-vote on an answer I'd posted which already had a down-vote (could it be from that deleted user?).

I don't know if this is a bug or if there is simply a delay between reputation updating, but I figured it was worth reporting.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly?tab=reputation

Sadly I cannot prove that I had 3,606 reputation yesterday.

Comment: Have you checked "Show removed posts" at the bottom of the page? It looks like also an answer with one up- and one downvote or a question with two up- and one downvote was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to check the *show removed posts* box at the bottom of the page for such rep changes to show up.

For a more detailed overview of your rep history, you can go to stackoverflow.com/reputation.